# Need an explanation on this code - c#

Tags: c#-3.0, delegates

I am getting familiar with C# day by day and I came across this piece of code

```
public static void CopyStreamToStream(
Stream source, Stream destination, 
Action<Stream,Stream,Exception> completed) {
byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
AsyncOperation asyncOp = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(null);

Action<Exception> done = e => {
    if (completed != null) asyncOp.Post(delegate { 
        completed(source, destination, e); }, null);
};

AsyncCallback rc = null;
rc = readResult => {
    try {
        int read = source.EndRead(readResult);
        if (read > 0) {
            destination.BeginWrite(buffer, 0, read, writeResult => {
                try {
                    destination.EndWrite(writeResult);
                    source.BeginRead(
                        buffer, 0, buffer.Length, rc, null);
                }
                catch (Exception exc) { done(exc); }
            }, null);
        }
        else done(null);
    }
    catch (Exception exc) { done(exc); }
};

source.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, rc, null);
```

}

From this article
[Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337900.aspx)

What I fail to follow is that how does the delegate get notified that the copy is done? Say after the copy is done I want to perform an operation on the copied file.

And yes I do know that this may beyond me given my few years in C#.

Answer (score 5):

The

```
done(exc);
```

and

```
else done(null);
```

bits execute the `Action<Exception>` which in turn will call the `Action<Stream, Stream, Exception>` passed into it using the `completed` parameter.

This is done using [`AsyncOperation.Post`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperation.post.aspx) so that the `completed` delegate is executed on an appropriate thread.

EDIT: You'd use it something like this:

```
CopyStreamToStream(input, output, CopyCompleted);
...

private void CopyCompleted(Stream input, Stream output, Exception ex)
{
    if (ex != null)
    {
        LogError(ex);
    }
    else
    {
        // Put code to notify the database that the copy has completed here
    }
}
```

Or you could use a lambda expression or anonymous method - it depends on how much logic you need.

Comment: Jon: If say I wanted to notify a DB that copy is done how would I set that in this code?

Comment: @ltech: You'd pass in an appropriate action (which notified the DB) as the argument for the `completed` parameter.

Comment: Jon: so would this change
Action<Exception> done = e => {
    if (completed != null) asyncOp.Post(delegate { 
        completed(source, destination, e); }, null);
};


to 
Action<Exception> done = e => {
    if (completed != null) asyncOp.Post(delegate { 
        completed(source, destination, e,DBWork()); }, null);
};

Comment: @ltech: Just for the sake of anyone else, you wouldn't *change* the method at all. You'd pass the relevant action *into* it, which would react to either success or failure based on whether an exception was thrown.

Comment: Jon: would be much obliged if you can provide snippet of above comment by you.

Answer (score 2):

The delegate gets wrapped in another delegate, called `done`. This is called in the `catch` blocks, as well as in the `else` block towards the end of the `AsyncCallback` delegate, that in turn is passed to `BeginRead`:

```
AsyncCallback rc = null;
rc = readResult => {
    try {
        int read = source.EndRead(readResult);
        if (read > 0) {
            destination.BeginWrite(buffer, 0, read, writeResult => {
                try {
                    destination.EndWrite(writeResult);
                    source.BeginRead(
                        buffer, 0, buffer.Length, rc, null);
                }
                catch (Exception exc) { done(exc); }  // <-- here
            }, null);
        }
        else done(null);   // <-- here
    }
    catch (Exception exc) { done(exc); }   // <-- and here
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The lines `done(...)` is where the delegate is being raised. The delegate is assigned earlier in the code i.e.

```
Action<Exception> done = e => {  
    if (completed != null) asyncOp.Post(delegate {   
        completed(source, destination, e); }, null);  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

@ltech - Can i use this to copy multiple files across a server? example: in a for loop Can i call this method and would it be the same as instantiating threads or invoking delegate via command pattern to move multiple files?